# Making animation as in "stripe/customers" for logos

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I want to make animation for my logos as in https://stripe.com/us/customers .

Maybe animation without shaking. But circles must go to the left side and spawn into right side again. I saw that div must be over screen size (at the site it have 3000px). I don't have any code, but any ideas is welcome

If it have js code, how I can do it with React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an easy and fast CSS-only solution:
Create an image with all your logos on it. Make it a nice grid of logos so that the image can be horizontally repeated. Animate the background position.

```css
@keyframes scrollbg {
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-1500px, 0, 0); /* width of the image */
  }
}

.banner-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  height: 300px;
  width: 4500px;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/g/1500/300?image=2") repeat-x;
  animation: scrollbg 35s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner-wrapper">
  <div class="banner"></div>
</section>
```